# How to create an audio wave in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to get an Audio wave plot using Chart Area in JavaFX. Unfortunately, I am not clear how to do, what are the values ​​to be extracted from the sound to assign to x-axis and y-axis? 
I  tried to read other posts, but I found nothing on javafx. 
You can help me?

---

Sample Image:

[image]

---

Below is the code that extract the waveform .

I'm pulling out the right parameters for my scope?

How can I use it to print the graph with JavaFX?

```
public class SimpleWaveformExtractor implements WaveformExtractor {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;

    @Override
    public double[] extract(File inputFile) {
        AudioInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot read audio file");
            return new double[0];
        }
        AudioFormat format = in.getFormat();
        byte[] audioBytes = readBytes(in);

        int[] result = null;
        if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 16) {
            int samplesLength = audioBytes.length / 2;
            result = new int[samplesLength];
            if (format.isBigEndian()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < samplesLength; ++i) {
                    byte MSB = audioBytes[i * 2];
                    byte LSB = audioBytes[i * 2 + 1];
                    result[i] = MSB << 8 | (255 & LSB);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < samplesLength; i += 2) {
                    byte LSB = audioBytes[i * 2];
                    byte MSB = audioBytes[i * 2 + 1];
                    result[i / 2] = MSB << 8 | (255 & LSB);
                }
            }
        } else {
            int samplesLength = audioBytes.length;
            result = new int[samplesLength];
            if (format.getEncoding().toString().startsWith("PCM_SIGN")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < samplesLength; ++i) {
                    result[i] = audioBytes[i];
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < samplesLength; ++i) {
                    result[i] = audioBytes[i] - 128;
                }
            }
        }

        return ArraysHelper.normalize(result);
    }

    private byte[] readBytes(AudioInputStream in) {
        byte[] result = new byte[0];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];

        try {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            do {
                bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                result = ArrayUtils.addAll(result, buffer);
            } while (bytesRead != -1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is the interface:

```
public interface WaveformExtractor {

    double[] extract(File in);
}
```

This is the code that return the array of double:

```
 private double[] extractWaveform(File file) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
     return new WavFileExtractor().extract(file);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a general question "how to plot a sound file", nothing specific about JavaFX.

Comment: could you  tell me some links please?

Comment: This should help you [Spectrum](https://github.com/pakoito/javafxmobile-plugin-ensemble/blob/master/src/main/java/ensemble/samples/charts/area/audio/AudioAreaChartApp.java)

Comment: @Bo Halim nice link!

Comment: Ok Margherita I will create some tutorials about this on youtube cause many people need this :) . Stay tuned.

Comment: hello, I continue to have problems in the graphic printing.
I think it's due to 'huge amount of points earned [about 200.000], that I slow down the program up to block it by not allowing to print the chart. How can I do?